# Laravel 4.2: Forcing seed on migrate:refresh in production

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, capistrano

As part of my Laravel 4.2 app, I'm running `artisan migrate:refresh --seed --force` in my Capistrano deployment, and I am getting the message:

```
*** Application In Production! *** 

Do you really wish to run this command?
```

Shouldn't --force bypass this?

I have noticed that this message occurs after the migrate:refresh has already run, but before the seed. Do I need to force the seed separately?

Thanks!

Comment: `--no-interaction` should do the job. You can always use `artisan migrate:refresh --force && artisan db:seed --force`

Comment: Excellent. Feel free to answer the question so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`--no-interaction` will do the job.

Other way would be such single call:

```
artisan migrate:refresh --force && artisan db:seed --force
```